# jumbled characters in opencart home page, site stopped working

Tags: opencart

im using opencart 1.5.6.4. I just cleared the cache and made a few changes mentioned in http://cartadvisor.com/blog/2013/11/05/speed-opencart-store/ to make my site speed.

now suddenly i get a list of jumbled characters. i dont see any error in the error logs and the site doesnt work

this is how the site looks now
[image]

i also replaced the htaccess, language files and reverted all the changes done but still i see the site like that.  i tried in several PCs it doesnt work now.

any reason why this has happened?

Comment: Encoding problems, BOM, incorrect/unsupported compression - to name a few. I would bet you forgot to turn off the GZip compression in your administration.

Comment: @shadyyx its set to zero. i tried setting different values but still the same.. the site was working fine. i added the nitro pack optimiation module and then cleared the cache but still i get the encoding error. any other place i need to look into?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to deactivate the OC output compression, go to System -> Settings -> Server and set "Output Compression Level:" to 0 - that worked well for me!